# Как уменьшить размер файла с индексом Сфинкса? И где этот файл хранится?

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Как можно посмотреть файл с индексом Сфинкса, сколько он занимает места, и где вообще находится?

Возможно ли уменьшить размер этого файла, например, заархивировав (пусть даже будет потеря скорости работы поиска)

Можно ли этот файл скопировать на другой сервер, без выполнения индексации заново, просто подключив?

Система - Ubuntu 18, находится на сервере (доступ только через терминал)

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно посмотреть файл с индексом Сфинкса, сколько он занимает места, и где вообще находится?

Ищите в конфиге сфинкса по path, там указан путь до файла индекса.

> Возможно ли уменьшить размер этого файла, например, заархивировав (пусть даже будет потеря скорости работы поиска)

Заархивировать нельзя. Можно только изменить структуру индекса, пожертвовав какими-либо атрибутами или полнотекстовыми полями или отключить min_prefix_len/min_infix_len или увеличить min_word_len. Можно еще поменять формат хранения словаря через dict=crc (не поддерживается в Sphinx 3, [поддерживается в Manticore Search](https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/singlehtml/index.html#dict) - форке Sphinx)

> Можно ли этот файл скопировать на другой сервер, без выполнения индексации заново, просто подключив?

Да, можно.